# Problems with response Google Compute Engine

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

I'm creating an GCE instance, there I installed apache2 and PHP in order to execute an application.

I have assigned the external IP to that instance in order to replicate the app; i have also got  the IP into my browser, the app opened in a correct way but then it got slowly.

Am I omitting something really important in the settings process?
I will be aware of your comments

Answer (score 1):

Performance depends on many factors, incl. the application itself of course.

In order to improve performance without changing the app/its setup, I'd suggest to try and increase instance size [get more cores] and/or increase disk size/use SSD.

Here is relevant documentation on the Compute Engine disk performance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdperformance